# Canvas's children and canvas's border overlap

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, border

I have a canvas placed into a grid. And the grid is placed into a border. When I draw some item (a white line for instance) on the canvas, this item lays over the border, so the border is erasing. Does anybody know how I can avoid it? I tried to set margin to the canvas, larger border's size than the canvas's one, but nothing helps.

This is my xaml:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"  BorderBrush="#333333" Opacity="1" Name="inner_canvas_border">
    <Grid Name="grid1">
        <Canvas Name="Canvas1"HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="700" Height="450" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of the `ClipToBounds` property on the `Canvas` is false.  Set this to true, and that will prevent elements that are outside of the bounds of the `Canvas` from displaying outside the bounds of the `Canvas`:

```
<Border
  BorderThickness="1"
  BorderBrush="#333333"
  Opacity="1"
  Name="inner_canvas_border">
  <Grid
    Name="grid1">
    <Canvas
      Name="Canvas1"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Width="700"
      Height="450"
      ClipToBounds="True" /><!-- This line here -->
  </Grid>
</Border>
```